# Is it possible to avoid the multiplication effect?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table “item” that can be associated with multiple “program”s and “topic”s. What I want when I query for items (by program ) is to get 1 row in the result set with the ids of programs and topics clumped together into 1 field. If this is possible, I don’t know how to do it. Can anyone offer me some advice to avoid getting the row multiplication effect of seeing every combination of program and topic in different rows in the result set?

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are experiencing a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), because there's no association between programs and topics directly.

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) if you want a comma-separated list of programs or topics "clumped" as you say. But just one expression per program and per topic.

```
SELECT item.*, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(program.some_col) AS clummped_programs,
 GROUP_CONCAT(topic.some_col) AS clumped_topics
FROM item
LEFT JOIN program ON ...
LEFT JOIN topic ON ...
GROUP BY item.id
```

But it's simpler and more maintainable to run multiple queries to avoid the Cartesian product.

```
SELECT item.*, program.*
FROM item
LEFT JOIN program ON ...

SELECT item.*, topic.*
FROM item
LEFT JOIN topic ON ...
```

It's tempting to try to make everything work in a single SQL query, but sometimes it's not the right way to approach the problem.